# What pylint options can be specified in inline comments?

Tags: python, pylint

I note that I can disable particular messages using a comment. For example, pylint by default complains about variable names of less than three letters. I can suppress that like this:

```
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
def some_string_operation(s):  # (the same thing here would also work)
    return something(s)
```

But I cannot, for example, add `s` to the good-names list. This doesn't work:

```
# pylint: good-names=s
def some_string_operation(s):
    return something(s)
```

So clearly not all options can be modified that way. Which ones can?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the module comments *you can only enable/disable specific PyLint checks*:

```
# pylint: disable=wildcard-import, method-hidden
# pylint: enable=too-many-lines
```

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, but feared it might be. Oh well. Is that documented anywhere? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Andrew looked through the documentation yesterday as well, but could not find a direct statement that would prove the answer - only indirect hints. May be I overlooked something though.