# Is it possible to specify a list of good names for pylint just within a single python file?

Tags: pylint, pylintrc

I'm looking for something like

```
[BASIC]
good-names=X,
           y
```

as in `pylintrc`, but I'd like to limit these names to be good only within a single python file.

I thought about message control like `#pylint: disable=invalid-names` on top of the file, but that is too broad. Ideally, I'd like to only allow these two invalid names `X` and `y` to be considered good within a single file. Is that possible with pylint?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It seems only enable/disable is possible in the file itself. Ref.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34803610/38281

Answer (score 0):

Only way I have been able to achieve this effect has been to `disable` and then immediately `enable` again immediately afterwards. It's not what you wanted but at least it doesn't ruin the whole file, and a comment of `# pylint: enable=xxx` is easy to find when you want to go cleaning up later on (like if they add good-names to in-file message control)